# What character might ler1 be for "不渗汤的面条"?

Tags: characters

《四川方言词典》contains the following entry:

> 干□儿
>
> gan1 ler1
>
> (名) 不渗汤的面条(川西南) ▷我不要汤，我要一碗～。

《成都方言》has a similar entry:

> 干溜
>
> gan1 liu1
>
> 不加汤：肝片儿还是～好吃。亦作“干熘”。

Where "□" [ler] from above could be 溜儿 or even 熘儿。

I'm leaning towards 溜 since 熘 seems to be quite specific in MSM (*一种烹调法，跟炒相似，作料里搀淀粉*).

Any ideas?

Comment: Cantonese have "乾撈" - dry stir (v) (adj) and "撈麵" - stirred noodle(n). the transliteration of 撈麵 (lo mein) is listed in English dictionaries

Comment: Northen dialect has a similar usage of 溜, one suck the noodles from plate to his mouth is called 溜, one suck the drug powder to his nose is called 溜冰.  冰 is 冰毒

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the words are correct. 干溜儿/干熘儿 is a kind of noodle in Chongqing. It's "real" name is 干溜面/干熘面, as you can see in [this](http://m.meishichina.com/recipe/180009/) recipe. It seems that the locals like to call it 干溜儿/干熘儿, as you can see from [this](https://www.xiaohongshu.com/discovery/item/59521851b46c5d4049e7d478) page or [this](https://m.toutiao.com/a3643210169/) page.

A search for both terms returned the same kind of noodles.